# How to setup a global variable in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I take inputs from users

In my index action i have:

```
    @b = Ece.find_by_code("#{params[:course]}")
```

I want to use the value stored in @b in my show action as well as in index action.

In my show action i want to do something like this:

```
<p><%= link_to "Forum", href="/courses/#{Course.find_by_courseCode(<%= @b %>).id}", :class=>"question_button round" %>
```

How can i setup @b to be global so that both these actions can use it

Note: Ece and Course are two different models

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just wanted to use a way to declare @b to be global.

and using $b instead of @b does the trick

Comment: Where do I need to declare it this? at the beginning of the clase or inside a specific method ['update', 'edit',...]?

Answer (score 9):

You could include it in a before filter like this:

```
before_filter :find_b, :only => [:index, :show]

# Standard controller actions here.

private
def find_b
  @b = Ece.find_by_code("#{params[:course]}")
end
```

Controller filters are a part of ActionController and you can find documentation on them [here](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html). In addition to before filters that run before an action there are also after filters and around filters which run around and after an action respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails it is not good practice to define `@b` somewhere you cannot see it being defined, as you may find it hard to figure our what's going on in the controller when you look back at it later on.

I suggest you set `@b` explicitly at the start of both the show and the index action: in other words, do repeat your

```
@b = Ece.find...
```

in each of the show and index actions - which is what you are already doing, I believe.

If you do want to clean up the controller code a bit, then do define a private function

```
private
def find_b(my_params)
    @b = Ece.find_by_code(my_params)
end
```

so that now your controller show and index actions set @b this way

```
@b = find_b("#{params[:course]}")
```

Now you have cleaner code, but at the same time you immediately know by looking at the controller that you are setting `@b` and that you are using `params` to do so.

As for the link you want to add in your show action, don't find the course `Course.find_by_courseCode` in the view - keep the view cleaner - and move that to the bit controller. So now your show action in the controller will have a line like this

```
@course = Course.find_by_id( @b.id )
```

and you can write your view link more cleanly as

```
<%= link_to 'Forum', @course, :class=>"question_button round" %>
```