# Passing data to the create method in rails with ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm pretty new to ruby on rails . I need to pass data from the view to create method in controller.

```
*view*
function setDeliveryDetails () {
    var all_del_rate= $('#all_dr').val();
    var all_del_period= $('#all_dp').val();
    var array=[all_del_rate,all_del_period]

  $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url:"save_delivary_details" ,
      dataType:"json",
      data: {deliveries: array},
      success:function(result){
          // alert(result);
      },
      error: function() {
      }
  });
}

*Controller*

def save_delivary_details
  @deliaddr = params[:deliveries]
end
```

and in the create method i coded

```
  logger.info("***#{@deliaddr} ")
```

but the parameters could not found in the rails console

Comment: whats the error message in your console ?

Comment: do you want `@deliaddr` inside `create` method? But you defined `@deliaddr` inside `save_delivary_details`, right?

Comment: no error it doesnt show the paramas that i except

Comment: @rony36 i need the solution for that i tried it using a global varaible but didnt work

Comment: @pasM try to write `puts "***#{@deliaddr} "`

Comment: @pasM also try `@deliaddr = params["deliveries"]` intsead of `@deliaddr = params[:deliveries]`

Comment: @pasM just updated my answer, please review

Comment: @puneet18 didnot work

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1: Define route of your controller:

```
# routes.rb
get '/save_delivary_details', controller: <:controller_name>, action: :save_delivary_details
```

#### Step 2: Define script with proper URL

```
function setDeliveryDetails () {
    var all_del_rate= $('#all_dr').val();
    var all_del_period= $('#all_dp').val();
    var array=[all_del_rate,all_del_period]

  $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url:"/save_delivary_details" ,
      dataType:"json",
      data: {deliveries: array},
      success:function(result){
          // alert(result);
      },
      error: function() {
      }
  });
}
```

#### Step 3: Get data inside controller action

Maybe you are looking for this (but it's nasty), [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136652/how-to-setup-a-global-variable-in-a-controller):

```
$deliaddr = []
def save_delivary_details
  $deliaddr = params[:deliveries]
end
```

And finally in `create` method:

```
logger.info("***#{$deliaddr} ")
```

## UPDATE (maybe you are looking for this)

In controller why don't you save this seliveryDetails in `DATABASE`? Or if delivery address is temporary and don't want to save it permanently, maybe you can store it in `session` in this way:

```
# in controller
def save_delivary_details
  session[:delivary_details] = params[:deliveries] # maybe you can make this `delivery_details` key unique by putting current_user id or something
end
```

And then inside `create` action you can retrieve it in this way:

```
def create
  logger.info("***#{session[:delivary_details]} ")
end
```

Hope it'll help you. Cheers!

Comment: yes that was what i lokking for but with the solution it wasn't happened. In this scenario this attributes should be saved provided that the object is saved. thats why i am seeking for a method to pass data to the create method

Comment: cant we pass  the variables directly to the create method

Comment: yes, we can, but on that trigger we have to execute whole `create` action. Is that okay for you?

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the controller symbol when parsing data from AJAX
Change your code like this. 
Your Controller is expecting the controller symbol in the beginning of parameters

```
  $.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:"/save_delivary_details" ,
  dataType:"json",
  data: {delivary_details: {deliveries: array}},
  success:function(result){
      // alert(result);
  },
  error: function() {
  }
});
```

This is my example

```
     $.ajax '/schedules',
          type: "POST",
          data: { schedule: { days: day_id_array, schedule_title: schedule_name, schedule_type: schedule_type}},
          async: true
          success:(data) ->
            if without_date == true
              location.href = "/schedules_without_date/" + data.id + '?saved=true&type=' + getScheduleType schedule_type
            else
              location.href = "/schedules/" + data.id + '?saved=true&type=' + getScheduleType schedule_type
            return false
```